# How to force child same virtual function call its parent virtual function first

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, oop

guys,
I have a case that needs the child class needs to call its parent virtual function at first before call its override virtual function.

```
BaseClass::Draw()
{

}

ChildClass::Draw()
{
    BaseClass::Draw(); // BaseClass Draw must be called first.
}

GrandChildClass::Draw()
{
    ChildClass::Draw(); // ChildClass Draw must be called first.
}
```

I want to hide this behavior from clients. Is there pattern on this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ : Call a base class method automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107974/c-call-a-base-class-method-automatically)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For simple cases you can use a second, private member function for the overrideable behavior:

```
class Base {
public:
    void Draw() { 
        // Base-class functionality here
        OverrideableDraw();
    }

private:
    virtual void OverrideableDraw() { }
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    virtual void OverrideableDraw() {
        // Derived-class functionality here
    }
};
```

---

For more complex hierarchies (e.g. where you have multiple levels of inheritance), this isn't possible since any derived class can override any virtual member function (there is no `final` in C++).  Usually it is safe to assume that each derived class is doing the right thing.  While I can think of a few times that I've run into issues because a derived class screwed up overriding, those cases were usually pretty straightforward to debug.

If you are really worried about it and really want to guarantee that base-class overrides are executed first, you could use something like this, though this is quite expensive (at least this naive implementation is quite expensive):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:

    Base() {
        RegisterDrawCallback(std::bind(&Base::DrawCallback, this));
    }

    void Draw() {
        for (auto it(drawCallbacks_.begin()); it != drawCallbacks_.end(); ++it)
            (*it)();
    }

protected:

    typedef std::function<void(void)> DrawCallbackType;
    typedef std::vector<DrawCallbackType> DrawSequence;

    void RegisterDrawCallback(DrawCallbackType f) {
        drawCallbacks_.push_back(f);
    }

private:

    void DrawCallback() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }

    DrawSequence drawCallbacks_;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:

    Derived() {
        RegisterDrawCallback(std::bind(&Derived::DrawCallback, this));
    }

private:

    void DrawCallback() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedDerived : public Derived {
public:

    DerivedDerived() {
        RegisterDrawCallback(std::bind(&DerivedDerived::DrawCallback, this));
    }

private:

    void DrawCallback() { std::cout << "DerivedDerived" << std::endl; }
};
```

[This is just one option; someone else can probably come up with a far more elegant solution.  Personally, I'd just make sure the virtual member functions are well-documented and leave it at that.]

Comment: In fact, [we should prefer to make virtual functions private, and provide public callers](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Comment: That seems not work on multiple levels of derivation hierarchy.

Comment: Yup, [Non-Virtual Interface idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).